# conditional check using primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

i am using primefaces to develop the application. I have a p:dataTable with refresh icon created using p:commandLink.Below is records.xhtml sample code:

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="SALES Information" />  
    <p:commandLink action="#{showMB.recordList}" update="salesInfo" ajax="true">
        <h:graphicImage library="images" name="show.jpg" title="Show Sales" height="20px;" width="20px;"/>
    </p:commandLink>
</f:facet>
```

Below is the method in ManagedBean:

```
  public List<RecordDTO> getRecordList() {
        boolean flag=true;
        try {
            if(dataList==null){
                //logic here
                flag=false;
            }
            if(dataList!=null){
                //Logic here
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return dataList;
    }
```

Now the issue is when i click the **p:commandLink** button, the control should always go 2nd if condition.

Please suggest. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why you don't use a method instead of a getter ? The datatable is feed by a getter of a list, you just have to edit the targeted list and update the datatable. I don't understand your way to do this...

Comment: add actionListener to the commandLink where you explicitly set dataList to null. actionListener is executed first before action So you will have datalist set to null before action method execution. But ideally you have to use actionListener only when the event source component instance is needed in backend raised. Hope this helps.

Comment: @SrikanthGanji - I modified as you mentioned , but still the control is going to if(dataList!=null && flag){...}.Please see the code which i modified in the above post.

Comment: What I mentioned was to add an actionListener in which you will make explicitly datalist null but not to remove action. You need to have both in your commandLink.

Comment: @SrikanthGanji - i tried as you mentioned but it was throwing exception for me. any sample code would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: action listner method signature should be 
public void actionListener(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent event) {
    datalist=null;
} and now your commandlink should be 
<p:commandLink action="#{showMB.getRecordList}" 
actionListener="#{showMB.actionListener}" update="recordsInfo" ajax="true">
                 <h:graphicImage library="images" name="show.jpg" title="Refresh"/>
               </p:commandLink>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a seperate actionListener where you will explicitly make datalist as null.

```
  public void actionListener(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent event) {  

      datalist=null;  
  }
```

And now your commandlink should be

```
  <p:commandLink action="#{showMB.getRecordList}" 
    actionListener="#{showMB.actionListener}" update="recordsInfo"   
     action="#{showMB.recordList}" ajax="true">  
   <h:graphicImage library="images" name="show.jpg" title="Refresh"/>  
 </p:commandLink>
```

ActionListener is executed first before action So you will have datalist set to null before action method execution.

But ideally you have to use actionListener only when the event source component instance is needed in backend raised.

Hope this helps.